# Creating taxonomic structure from individual records

Tags: xslt

I am having a failure of imagination in how to effectively solve this problem. My actual data set has thousands of thousands of records. Each record indicates its location in a taxonomic structure. I need to create that taxonomic structure and place the records within that structure (e.g., records that indicate they go in "/a/b/c" end up in the "/a/b/c" but there is only one each of the taxonomic levels "a", "b", and "c").  Due to client confidentiality, I've posted a naive representation of this here.

Using XSLT 3 is desirable. I know there is a solution to this using xsl:iterate but I cannot figure it out.

Input:

```
<outer>
    <record>
        <id>rec1</id>
        <taxNodes>
            <node>
                <id>1</id>
                <note>First level</note>
                <node>
                    <id>node2a</id>
                    <note>Second level Entry A</note>
                </node>
            </node>
        </taxNodes>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>rec3</id>
        <taxNodes>
            <node>
                <id>1</id>
                <note>First level</note>
                <node>
                    <id>node2b</id>
                    <note>Second level Entry B</note>
                </node>
            </node>
        </taxNodes>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>rec4</id>
        <taxNodes>
            <node>
                <id>1</id>
                <note>First level</note>
                <node>
                    <id>node2b</id>
                    <note>Second level Entry B</note>
                </node>
            </node>
        </taxNodes>
    </record>
</outer>
```

Desired Output:

```
<outer>
    <node>
        <id>1</id>
        <note>First level</note>
        <node>
            <id>node2a</id>
            <note>Second level Entry A</note>
            <records>
                <record>
                    <id>rec1</id>
                </record>
            </records>
        </node>
        <node>
            <id>node2b</id>
            <note>Second level Entry B</note>
            <records>
                <record>
                    <id>rec3</id>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <id>rec4</id>
                </record>
            </records>
        </node>
    </node>
</outer>
```

Comment: I don't understand how the input relates to the desired output: why is `node` with `id` as `node2a` nested in the input and in the output in the `node` with `id` as `1` while the `node` `node2b` is only nested in the output but not in the input? And why is `node` with `id` as `1` having `<note>First level</note>` at some places in the input and `<note>First record</note>` at other places?

Comment: That was pure, unadulterated sloppiness on my part. I have revised the input and output examples to be correct. I have also since posting this question developed a solution to this, which I've posted as an answer, but there has to be a more efficient solution than what I've come up with. Thank you, Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be seen as a grouping problem and then solved using a recursive function using `xsl:for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math mf"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="input-nodes" as="element(node)*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$input-nodes" group-by="id">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="id, note"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()/node">
                        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()/node)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <records>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/ancestor::record"/>
                        </records>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="outer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(record/taxNodes/node)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That gives the desired result I think for the input sample you have posted, I am not sure it will do for other inputs, mainly as I am not sure how variable the input can be, I think if I understand the spec 'there is only one each of the taxonomic levels "a", "b", and "c"' correctly then it should work fine.

As for having a huge input file and using XSLT 3.0 (with streaming?), I am not sure that a streaming solution is possible, due to the nature of the problem where we need to recursively group the whole set of input `node`s.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. That is what I was looking for. It was putting the for-each-group in the function and using recursion that I was failing to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet provides a solution but does so using a function for looping.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:local="http://www.local.com"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs local"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="maxTaxonomyDepth" select="max(//node[not(node)]/count(ancestor-or-self::node))" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="local:getTaxNodesForDepth(outer, 1, $maxTaxonomyDepth, '')" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="local:getTaxNodesForDepth">
        <xsl:param name="out" as="element()" />
        <xsl:param name="curDepth" as="xs:integer" />
        <xsl:param name="maxDepth" as="xs:integer" />
        <xsl:param name="parentId" as="xs:string*" />
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($out/record/taxNodes//node[count(ancestor-or-self::node) = $curDepth]
            [if ($curDepth > 1) then parent::node/id/normalize-space(.) = $parentId else true()]
            /id/normalize-space(.))">
            <xsl:variable name="context" select="." as="xs:string" />
            <node>
                <xsl:sequence select="($out/record/taxNodes//node[count(ancestor-or-self::node) = $curDepth][id/normalize-space(.) = $context])[1]/(id | descriptor)" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$out/record[taxNodes/descendant::node[last()][id/normalize-space(.) = $context]]" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$curDepth &lt; $maxDepth">
                        <xsl:sequence select="local:getTaxNodesForDepth($out, $curDepth + 1, $maxDepth,
                            ($out/record/taxNodes//node[count(ancestor-or-self::node) = $curDepth][id/normalize-space(.) = $context])[1]/id/normalize-space(.))" />
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </node>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="taxNodes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#default">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="#current"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```